# Table inside a table adding padding

Tags: html, css, browser

If you look at: [this website I built](http://www.portroyaleec.co.uk/), I would like the sidebar weather that is added via javascript to be center aligned. When I look at this in Firebug it looks like the inner padding is from the tables.

Comment: Hint #1: don't use tables for what are list-structures; #2: reset margin's and padding's…

Comment: Yes I know this, if you check the rest of the website it is built correctly. Its the horrible javascript weather API that is causing the problem and adding the tables. I obviously can't change the contents of an iframe with the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is larger than its container because of its last `<td>` which contains

> yourweather.co.uk   +info

As you cannot modify its code I sugger you to use a "real" API like [Yahoo! Weather](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#params) instead of a ugly iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your content is a iframe from a weather page that is on another server and because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) ([2](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/JavaScript-Security/)) you can't alter the table within the iframe to fit your div. So either you make your div bigger, use scroll bars or if you have contact with the owner of the weather server ask him to edit his page so it will fit for you.